# How to create a link for seller's token?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am in the process of developing a software using the Amazon MWS API for other Amazon sellers. Until now, I was using my own private info:
(access key, secret key, seller id , market place id, Auth token)

1. Is the US market place id the same for every market place, i.e for all sellers?
2. In my software, I am using the 5 identifiers above. But when someone grants a developer access, there are only 3 identifiers (seller id , market place id , auth token). If I don't fill the other 2 in the requests, will it work? If not, what should I do to get the other 2?
3. Most important: I don't want to ask the user to type my developer number, and I saw in other software that they provide a link directly to the "Accept the Amazon MWS License Agreement to give access to my Amazon Seller Account with MWS" page. How do I create this link?

Answer (score 0):

The marketplace ID is unique for each region http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html

You need to supply seller ID, marketplace ID, along with your access key ID and secret key.  The marketplace ID and seller ID (which is the same as merchant id) is the same for all developers that have access to MWS for that seller account.  Each developer would have their own access key id and secret key.  It's been a long time since I've been on those screens, but I believe I signed up for MWS access as a developer, and then gave that ID to my client who authorized access to their account for me.   Check out this link: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything about a link straight to the "Accept the Amazon MWS License Agreement to give access to my Amazon Seller Account with MWS".

I have always instructed them to login at the correct url (based on marketplace), enter my dev id and return to my platform to manually input their token. As the [Amazon docs](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html#webAppIntegrator) suggest.